# How to align content with motion layout?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-motionlayout

I have made a collapsible top app bar in jetpack compose using a motion layout. The app bar actually contains a box with a swipeable modifier and its anchors are mapped to swiping state `COLLAPSED` and `EXPANDED`. The problem is that the content which should align under the top app bar is actually being hidden under the top app bar when it is expanded.

[image] [image]

Any suggestions of how could i constraint the content with the top app bar so the content changes its height according to the swipe state.

kotlin

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMotionApi::class, ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun UserData(
    user: User
) {

    val swipingState = rememberSwipeableState(initialValue = SwipingStates.EXPANDED)
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val motionScene = remember {
        context.resources
            .openRawResource(R.raw.motion_scene)
            .readBytes()
            .decodeToString()
    }
    MotionLayout(
        progress =  if (swipingState.progress.to == SwipingStates.COLLAPSED) swipingState.progress.fraction
        else 1f - swipingState.progress.fraction,
        motionScene = MotionScene(content = motionScene),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
    {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(LightBlue)
                .layoutId("box")
                .swipeable(
                    state = swipingState,
                    thresholds = { _, _ -> FractionalThreshold(0.5f) },
                    orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                    anchors = mapOf(
                        0f to SwipingStates.EXPANDED,
                        400f to SwipingStates.COLLAPSED,
                    )
                )
        )

    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model =
        ImageRequest
            .Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(user.imageUrl)
            .build()
    )
    Image(
        painter = painter,
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .border(2.dp, Color.White, CircleShape)
            .layoutId("profile_pic"),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
    )

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .layoutId("details"),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    )
    {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 13.dp),
            text = user.email,
            fontSize = 18.sp,
            color = Color.White
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(5.dp))
        Text(text = "Boards : ", fontSize = 18.sp, color = Color.White)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(5.dp))
        Text(text = "Cards : ", fontSize = 18.sp, color = Color.White)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
        androidx.compose.material3.Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(110.dp)
                .padding(start = 10.dp),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Blue.copy(0.2f)),
            onClick = {

            }) {
            Text(text = "LogOut", color = Color.White)

        }

    }
    Text(
        text = user.userName,
        fontSize = 24.sp,
        color = Color.White,
        modifier = Modifier.layoutId("username")
    )
}
}
```

This is my composable which contains the motion layout.

Comment: Please show some code instead of attaching screenshots. That would be helpful for replicating the issue.

Comment: @UmeshP I have uploaded the code.

Comment: Your text is same color as your app bar, so I'm not even sure it goes under or over, as both cases would look the same.

Comment: @Agent_L The problem is not with the text going under or over the app bar , but it is with the alignment of the TextView(or any other composable, i have added a TextView just for example) with the app bar, I want the content to shift vertically as the app bar expands.

Comment: In the screen shot above i have added a Box below the top app bar and the box has fillMaxSize() modifier as i wanted it to take the whole remaining space, and the content alignment of the box is TopStart but the TextView appears at the same bounds where the app bar is fully expanded, so I think that the top app bar is by default taking the whole height of its expanded state even when it is not expanded.

Comment: I am not sure it is possible to tell what is going wrong. With just the code above. There is some little mistakes (Box(.....fillMaxWidth())but I do not think its your problem. You can do 3 things: 1 Post a full self contained composable that demonstrates the problem. 2: add more files (where is "dsjgn"?). Look at/copy some examples of similar effects from https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/tree/main/demoProjects/ExamplesComposeMotionLayout#motionlayout-simple-colapasing-toolbar

Comment: @hoford thankyou, the github link helped me and i have implemented some thing like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by putting the whole screen view inside the Box composable and managed the swipe using nestedScrollConnection.
These are the link that helped me

https://youtu.be/XS7G3iSVWNE

and the github link mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Where are the links?